# Function call unresolved reference

Tags: python, function

for my coding course we had to make a lottery odds calculator, which has to include 2 functions and a main function. However, when I am trying to call one funtion to the main one I get the unresolved reference error. I don't know why it is doing it, this is the first exercise where I have 2 functions and a main. It might be that I have 2 bad/useless functions, since the instructions said to choose whatever functions seem logical.

```
from math import factorial

def fraction(prob):

    frac=1/prob
    return frac


def winProb(total, drawn):

    facTot=factorial(total)
    facDraw=factorial(drawn)
    facBoth=factorial(total-drawn)

    prob = float(facTot/(facBoth*facDraw))
    return prob

def main():

    total=int(input("Enter the total number of lottery balls: "))
    drawn=int(input("Enter the number of the drawn balls: "))

    if total < 0:
        print("The number of balls must be a positive number.")
    elif drawn <0:
        print("The number of balls must be a positive number.")
    elif drawn > total:
        print("At most the total number of balls can be drawn.")
    else:
        print("The probability of guessing all", drawn, "balls correctly is 1/", fraction(prob))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Unresolved reference comes when I try to call fraction(prob) in the last line

Comment: can you please add the erroneous code and the exact error?

Comment: You haven't set prob

Comment: I don't know if you shared the complete code but nowhere before the last line you are referencing the variable `prob`. That might be the cause of your problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full error probably tells you that `prob` is undefined. While you may have defined it within `winProb` it is out of the scope of `main` so it doesn't exist there yet. You need to define `prob` right after `total` and `drawn` within `main`:

```
prob = winProb(total, drawn)
```

Alternatively, replace `fraction(prob)` with `fraction(winProb(total, drawn))`